# Configuring Google App Engine host location

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Because of the way Google App Engine is designed, I am under the impression that what I'm about to ask is not achievable but, you never know.

I have a application deployed to the Google App Engine, when verifying login (via HTTP Post) to a third party site, the site requires that I am from a certain geographical location (preferably the UK). 
As a resident of the UK, when in a local development environment, I am able to authenticate with this third party site without any issue. However, when deployed to GAE I cannot be sure where my app is hosted.

Is there any way at all to choose preferable host location with GAE?
Or maybe as a resident of the UK I am able to use a workaround through a Google API that is legitimate, i.e. one which does not involve proxy changes etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "fake" your servers IP location when making direct TCP connections. That holds for  AppEngine or on any other server. The only way around it is to use a proxy server (they should cost around 10EUR a month).

As @kunai mentions, google gives an option of EU-hosted servers if you have a premier account. I don't know if this would help in your situation as it seems you need a UK-based location.

Answer (score 0):

From the Java GAE [Changelog](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes#Version_1.7.0_-_June_26,_2012) :

> Premier customers now have the option to create applications to be
>   served from datacenters located in the European Union.

Also documented in the blog post [here](http://googleappengine.blogspot.in/2012/06/google-app-engine-170-released-at.html) (Although the link there seems to be dead).

Disclaimer: I have not used this myself.